# How do I test receiving mail as not-logged-in user in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I am using Django on GAE. On my local development server I have associated a django `view` function with email receiving address:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^_ah/mail/(.*)', 'core.views.handle_email')
)
```

As far as I understand, `core.views.handle_email` now receives all of the incoming emails for my application. That actually works. I *am able to see* that it works by sending emails to my application from application console `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/inboundmail`. But this works *only if I am logged in* to my application. If I am not looged in, I *cannot send any email* from `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/inboundmail`. But I still need to test behavior of my application in this case.

So the exact question is: how do I test receiving emails when application is not logged in?

Comment: Does handle_email have admin_required or login required decorators?

Comment: @Bert, sorry, something went wrong and my first answer wasn't uploaded. 
No, I do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On App Engine (live), when an inbound mail is sent to your application, an admin login will be used to send the request, so I don't think you need to worry about testing the "non-logged in" case.

Comment: But still, is there a way to send an email to the non-logged-in GAE application on development server?

Comment: @ikostia, Do you have admin_required or login_required on your handler?

Comment: not quite sure how inbound mail handlers are setup with django, but if you have "- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script:<your handler>
  login: admin" you could comment out login:admin

Comment: does that affect application console? Because at the moment the main issue is to send email, not to receive it.

Comment: When login:admin is removed from app.yaml definition for inbound mail, you can send mail (to your inbound mail handler) without needing to login.

Comment: thanks. Somehow I thought that those option affects something else. Does GAE documentation cover that somewhere?